# Why is this returning some objects as promises?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a messaging system on a website that I'm making. I'm trying to get the sender's name from a database. I have async/await and the result from my function where I get an object with each message ID and the sender's name is returning a promise. Here is my function:

```js
async function getMessageSenders(){
    let senders = {}
    inbox.forEach(async (message) => {
      if (message.sender === 'Baseball Stats') {
        senders[message.id] = message.sender
      } else {
        senders[message.id] = await database.users.where('uid', '==', message.sender)
        .get()
        .then((q) => {
          return q.docs.map((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data()
            return data.displayName
          })
        })
      }
    })
    return senders
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this expression `senders[message.id] = await database.users.where('uid', '==', message.sender)` assigns a promise actually, not a value. If you want to assign a value, you should put it in the `.then()` callback, like:

```
async function getMessageSenders(){
    let senders = {}
    inbox.forEach(async (message) => {
      if (message.sender === 'Baseball Stats') {
        senders[message.id] = message.sender
      } else {
        await database.users.where('uid', '==', message.sender)
        .get()
        .then((q) => {
          const promises = q.docs.map((doc) => {
            return doc.data()
          })
          Promises.all(promises).then(data => {
             senders[message.id] = data.map(item => item.displayName)
          })
        })
      }
    })
    return senders
  }
```

Comment: Still giving me the same result unfortunately

Comment: let's figure it out then: what is `doc.data()` you calling? maybe this returns promise as well?

Comment: Yes, I just checked and `doc.data()` returns a promise

Comment: edited my answer, try smth like this, so you should resolve all promises and assign to your senders then

Comment: Still returning any item that isn't "Baseball Stats" as a promise. Could it have something to do with `return senders` at the end of the function?

Comment: hm, where do you check this? try to console log in the callback `Promises.all(promises).then`. Also please note that `getMessageSenders()` returns promise as well.